# how to show the result of a query on my website

Tags: php, mysql

so I want to show the result of my query, and I can't seem to find anything that works.
this is what I have so far and I have no idea why it won't work.

```
daydream festival <?php
$queryday="SELECT `tickets_MAX`-`tickets_VERKOCHT` AS `tickets_over` FOR `evenementdata`        WHERE `ev id`=1";
$resultday=mysql_query($queryday);
$rowday = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultday);
echo $rowday;?> tickets left
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact that you're using the deprecated mysql_* functions, have you done *any* debugging? What errors do you get? Do you connect to the database?

Comment: There's a _pretty good_ chance that `ev id` is not actually the name of one of your columns.

Comment: You can't print the assoc right away (it's an array). Use `echo $rowday['tickets_over']`. Also I'm not sure if you can use subtractions that way, you may need to call a function for it.

Comment: @j08691 thanks for solving at least one problem for me: it didn't connect to the database because of a typo. now I get an error: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in I:\root\tickets.php on line 13 (line 13 starts with $rowday)

Comment: are you sure that your query string is correct?  maybe "ev id" is really "ev_id"?  Also, try using var_dump($resultday) to see what you're actually getting.  That being said, if everything works, $rowday should be an array, so you need to loop through the array before you echo it, use print_r instead

Comment: if I use var_dump I get bool(false) when I look at the website

Comment: I have tried using print_r by the way, it still doesn't work

Comment: there is more than likely something wrong with your query string.  Are you sure FOR shouldn't be FROM? mysql_query() only returns false on error or if you dont have permission to access the table http://us1.php.net/mysql_query

Answer (score 0):

Building on other reasons why this won't print anything like your rows not existing, or misnaming things.

If I'm not mistaken mysql_fetch_assoc returns an array, echo does not print arrays.  You need to use print_r($rowday); - Assuming that $rowday contains data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few assumptions here, but I think it's likely that you should do it like:

```
<?php
$queryday="SELECT `tickets_MAX`-`tickets_VERKOCHT` AS `tickets_over` FROM `evenementdata` WHERE `ev_id`=1";
$resultday=mysql_query($queryday);
$rowday = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultday);
print_r($rowday);
?>
```

That being said, I would strongly recommend not using the mysql_ functions, since they are now being depreciated.  You should do some research into [The PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).

Comment: I'm really glad it worked! Btw, the best way to show appreciation on Stack Overflow if someone helps to solve your problem is to upvote their answer and mark it as solved :)